# How to retrieve data from a client component form in a server component using POST method?

Tags: forms, next.js

//this is my client component in: Form/page.tsx

```
"use client"
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function Form() {

  const [name, setName] = useState('')

  const handleSubmit = async () => {

    try {
      const response = await fetch('/ReceiveName', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ name }),
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        // Handle success
        console.log('Name added successfully');
        // Optionally, I can reset the name state here
        setName('');
      } else {
        // Handle errors
        console.error('Error adding name');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor="name">Search</label>
      <input id="name"
            name="name"
            type="text"
            value={name}
            onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  )
}
```

---

//This is my server componen in: ReceiveName/route.tsx

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

async function ReceiveName(request: Request) {
    const name = request.body; 

    // console to demonstrate the data receiving on the server
     console.log(name);

     // Return a response
     NextResponse.status(200).json({ message: 'User added successfully' });
}
```

---

I´m new to Next.js and is driven me crazy to send form data (please help!!)

I just tried to add a name in the form, submit it and retrieve it in the server side using POST method.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your do not retrieve code from BE correctly. You should update your BE.

```
async function POST(request: Request) {
    const requestData = await request.json(); 

    // console to demonstrate the data receiving on the server
     console.log(requestData);

     // Return a response. You can also pass response back to FE. For example whatever string
      return NextResponse.json(
      { message: "Name updated", response: { whatever: 'Whatever'} },
      { status: 200 }
    );
}
```

Comment: The answer was correct. I also have to change the name of the function to "POST".

Comment: Ah, you right missed it. You can also name handler and below write export { handler as GET, handler as POST }; if you prefer.